# pre-compile asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

we have a asp.net 2.0 website created in visual studio using asp.net website model. So, every time I need to deploy the website to the production server, I go to visual studio and right click on the website and select "publish website". I will check the first 2 options. "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" and "use fixed naming assemblies". In the Target location, I specify the folder name in my local machine. Once it is published successfully, I copy the contents from the local folder to the website folder in iis. Does this mean that I am precompiling the website. After copying the website, I don't see instant response to the pages. Initially it takes some time to load as if it is compiling at that time. After that, If I go to the same page again, it is fast. So, I don't think I am doing precompile but I am not sure.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you choose option *"Allow this precompiled site to be updatable"*, it means that only code files (including code-behind) gets compiled. The markup (aspx, ascx, ashx etc) does not get compiled at all - that get parsed and compiled at runtime only on first visit. On plus side, you can make changes to your aspx/ascx files at deployed site and changes will take effect on next visit (due to re-compilation).

If you don't choose above option then all files will get compiled at publishing time and you won't get performance hit that you are seeing on first visit. However, for any change, you have to re-compile/publish the entire site. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/399f057w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to understand these differences.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that. I will try this. we always deploy the whole site. so, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think this MSDN page can give you more information about the "Alllow this precompiled site to be updated" option.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377y0s6t(v=vs.80).aspx